# Получить атрибут новости, на котором кликнули

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Как получить атрибут новости, на котором кликнули

```
$(".Voting .voteUp").click(function(){
    var id = $('#newsId').attr('value');
});

$(".Voting .voteDown").click(function(){
    var id = $('#newsId').attr('value');
});

<div class="Voting">
    <div class="votes" data-news="2">
        <div class="voteUp">
            <a class="icon-vote-up"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="votesNumber">1</span>
        <div class="voteDown">
            <a class="icon-vote-down"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="newsId" />
</div>
<div class="Voting">
    <div class="votes" data-news="1">
        <div class="voteUp">
            <a class="icon-vote-up"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="votesNumber">0</span>
        <div class="voteDown">
            <a class="icon-vote-down"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="newsId" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день, если я Вас правильно понял, то:

```
$(function(){
        $(".Voting .voteUp").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).closest('.Voting').children('input').attr('value');
        }); 
});
```